# Из String в HWND и из HWND в String

Tags: delphi

Не подскажете как в delphi перевести типы данных из String в HWND и из HWND в String?

Comment: А разве IntToStr(a:Int64 (или Integer)) не помогает? У меня так работает, т. к. HWND - подмножество Int64. StrToInt(S: String): Int64 - наоборот. Хотя, при большом значении всё-таки не работает. Эти функции всё-таки с типом Integer работают, но почему-то в подсказке к типу данных, всплывает Integer и Int64, я сначала решил, что это перегрузка.

Comment: Не получается

Comment: Могу, как вариант (скорее всего не самый лучший), предложить следующее: для преобразования из строкового типа разбить строку на части и перевести в числа обычным способом, одно из этих чисел умножить на определённую степень 10-ки, и прибавить к ней оставшуюся часть; а для преобразования числа в строку использовать операции Div и Mod (выделять все цифры числа необязательно), выделить одну часть и другую, преобразовать в 2 строки и сложить их.

Answer (score 1):

Написал этот пример, исходя из мыслей комментария, вроде пашет правильно.

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Math;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

Var
  hw: HWND;
  Str: String;
  i: Byte;

Function HWNDToStr(Const hw: HWND): String;
Var
  Str1, Str2: String;
  i1, i2: Integer;
Begin
  Result:='';
  i1:=hw Div 10000;
  i2:=hw Mod 10000;
  Str1:=IntToStr(i1);
  Str2:=IntToStr(i2);

  If (Str1='0') Then
    Result:=Str2
  Else
    Result:=Str1+Str2;
End;

Function StrToHWND(Const Str: String): HWND;
Var
  Str1, Str2: String;
  Res: LongWord;
  i1, i2: Integer;
  i: Byte;
Begin
  i:=1;
  While ((Str[i] In ['0'..'9']) And (i<Length(Str))) Do
    Inc(i);

  If (i<Length(Str)) Then
    Begin
      Result:=0;
      Exit;
    End;

  If (Length(Str)>5) Then
    Begin
      Str1:='';
      Str2:='';

      For i:=1 To 5 Do
        Str1:=Str1+Str[i];

      For i:=6 To Length(Str) Do
        Str2:=Str2+Str[i];

     //  с этими функциями работает неправильно (не стал разбираться почему)
     //  Delete(Str1, 5, Length(Str)-5);
     //  Delete(Str2, 1, 5);

      i1:=StrToInt(Str1);
      i2:=StrToInt(Str2);
      Res:=i1*Round(IntPower(10, Length(Str)-5))+i2;

      Result:=HWND(Res);
    End
  Else
    Result:=StrToInt(Str);
End;

begin
  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To 9 Do
    Begin
      hw:=Random(High(HWND));
      Str:=HWNDToStr(hw);

      WriteLn('--------------');
      WriteLn('hw = ', hw, ' Str = ', Str);
      hw:=StrToHWND(Str);
      WriteLn('hw = ', hw, ' Str = ', Str);
    End;

  ReadLn;
end.
```